# Parallelism in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I am new to Apache Storm and trying to design a simple topology for my use case. The explanation for parallelism in Storm ([Understanding the Parallelism of a Storm Topology](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html)) has left me with two queries:

1) Is it safe to assume that same worker will have the executors  for
    my spout as well as bolt if i have only one worker?

2) The inter worker communication uses ZeroMQ which uses network for communication as opposed to LMX Disruptors 
    used for intra-worker communication, which are faster as they are in-memory. Should I create a single worker for better performance?

Please answer the above queries and correct my understanding if incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) yes

2) Using one worker per topology per machine is recommended since intra process communication is much more expensive in Storm.
refer to : https://storm.apache.org/documentation/FAQ.html
On my experience basis also, using multiple workers in one machine for same topology have negative impact on throughput.